# Dependency Injection - Symfony (There is no extension able to load the config for "acme_api.question_manager" (in ../Resources/config/services.yml)

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Getting this error while setting up new services using DI in symfony2
I am using symfony2.3 and using fos-rest bundle to create json API's

- Here is how my code looks like

DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your     app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @return TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $treeBuilder->root('acmeapi');


        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

DependencyInjection/AcmeApiExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class AcmeApiExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        //$loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        //$loader->load('services.xml');

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'acme_api';
    }
}
```

And my Resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters: 
    # Overriding Security Bundle's Access Listener class to provide  detailed
    # error message
services:
acme_api.question_manager:
    class: AcmeApiBundle\Manager\QuestionManager
    arguments:
      - @doctrine
      - @validator
```

And finally the app/confog/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @AcmeApiBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
.......
```

Also, adding the appkernel file

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Acme\ApiBundle\AcmeApiBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    { 
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any more data points are required, so that its easy to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing config.yml and services.yml. First one contains bundle configuration, the second one services and parameters.

services.yml is already loaded in `class AcmeApiExtension` in line `$loader->load('services.yml');`, so there is no need to load it once again with:

`- { resource: @AcmeApiBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }`.

(Loading services with extension is most common way for bundles). For additional information take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-other-container-configuration-resources

Also there is a formatting error in services.yml. Correct one:

```
parameters: 
    # Overriding Security Bundle's Access Listener class to provide  detailed
    # error message
services:
    acme_api.question_manager:
        class: AcmeApiBundle\Manager\QuestionManager
        arguments:
          - @doctrine
          - @validator
```

(indentation for last 5 lines). And this causes "No extension" error.

Comment: thanks a ton. I wasn't loading in both the places, that was one after another. The formatting in yaml was the real issue.